# How to add text outline on html button

Tags: html, css, button, text

I want to make the button text like this [image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution provided by [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287047/kyle) on the same question some time ago.

```css
.strokeme
{
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="strokeme">
    TEST
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-86deg, blue, #Fefefe);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-stroke: 20px transparent;
```

to your text css.

Codepen.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyOROr

Answer (score 0):

Other solution are similar to mine, but I just added CSS on `button`

```css
button {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#02bbff, #258eb5);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-stroke: 15px transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 15px transparent; 
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Enter</button>
```